# Date range to include end date

Tags: datetime, postdate

I am grabbing a date range from a URL query string like so:

```
https://website.com/qa/search-feedback-results?datestart=2019-01-01&dateend=2019-02-26
```

I can't figure out how to include posts that were submitted on the end date that is in the range. In the above example, any posts dated `2019-02-26` are not showing up in my results.

Here's my code:

```
{% set vDatestart = craft.app.request.getParam('datestart')|date('Y-m-d') %}
{% set vDateend = craft.app.request.getParam('dateend')|date('Y-m-d') %}
{% set vParams = vParams|merge({ postDate: ['and', '>= ' ~ vDatestart, '<= ' ~ vDateend] }) %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried setting a time for the end date? because I think Craft always saves time with your date fields.

```
{% set vDateend = craft.app.request.getParam('dateend')|date('Y-m-d') ~ ' 23:59:59' %}
```